# amazon web services + ruby on rails + cloudformation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

i am trying to deploy a sample ruby on rails  in aws using cloud formation . can anyone guide me how to deploy as all the sample templates , provided by aws or mine are getting rolled back and getting deleted automatically

Comment: Can you share the logs when your Cloud Formation template is processing?

Comment: maybe you should use Elastic Beanstalk. What's your reason to choose CloudFormation?

Comment: While launching the Cloud formation stack, in the last page go on Advanced and check "Don't roll back on Failure" then launch the cloudformation stack and when it fails collect the logs and provide some logs for analysis here. Later delete the stack manually.